# autocomplete in YUI is very slow in IE6 on large dataset

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yui

Trying to use autocomplete functionality of YUI, we ran into the fact that it's **extremely** slow on **IE6** for a datasource containing 30000 items (when trying to type in an autocomplete field, it takes several MINUTES for IE to respond).

However, the same exact code works pretty much real-time in IE8.

Are we doing something wrong? Can we optimize this somehow? Is IE6+YUI autocomplete not designed for such large datasets?

Here's our code initializing the autocompleter:

```
Y.namespace( 'YAHOO.program' );
Y.program.AllTreeItemsArr = new Array();
// Populate the array with 30000 elements
Y.program.BasicLocal = function() {
        var oDS = new YU.LocalDataSource(Y.program.AllTreeItemsArr);
        oDS.responseSchema = {fields : ["portfolio"]};
        var oAC = new Y.widget.AutoComplete("selected"
                                          , "autocomplete_container", oDS);
        oAC.prehighlightClassName = "yui-ac-prehighlight";
        oAC.useShadow = true;
        oAC.typeAhead = true;
        oAC.queryDelay = .05;
        oAC.typeAheadDelay = .5;

        return {
            oDS: oDS,
            oAC: oAC
        };
     }();
```

And here's the HTML to use it:

```
    <span id="port_autocomplete" class="yui-skin-sam" style='position: relative;'>
         <input type='text' id='selected' maxlength=10 name='selected'
                value='' isSelected=1 onkeyup="searchOnEnter();">
         <div id="autocomplete_container" style="position: absolute"></div>
    </span>
```

The `searchOnEnter` function is a standard "catch a keypress and execute a search JS function if key == 13".

Comment: It is hard to say without some profiler data. Try profiling your app with Dynatrace (it supports IE6 I think) http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/ with a smaller subset of data and see what's running slow.

Comment: Where is the question here? Of course IE6 is slow, plus why are you initializing it with such a large data set?

Comment: @Chaos: The questions were mid-way in the post: "Are we doing something wrong? Can we optimize this somehow? Is IE6+YUI autocomplete not designed for such large datasets?"

Comment: @Chaos: I know IR6 is slow. But I have trouble believing it is several orders of magnitude slow (several minutes vs. sub-second response difference)

Comment: @Chaos: because we need a search field across that dataset (which is already present in the page).

Comment: One page I wrote ran in seconds in Firefox and minutes in IE6. It really is that much slower.

Comment: Oh my apologies for my poor reading comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is that IE has a slow JS engine, and 30000 records is a lot of data.  However, the filtering operation does include one call that may be the root of your trouble.  Try this patch out and see if it makes a difference:

http://gist.github.com/316358

Comment: @Luke - I will certainly try that. May I inquire what changed from YUI? I tried to compare the logic of YUI's native filterResults and it seems pretty much identical with exception of support for "start of string only" logic in YUI's?

Comment: Other than some micro optimizations and the stuff you noted, the key line removed was

oParsedResponse = YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete._cloneObject(oParsedResponse);

That did a deep copy of the unfiltered response that contains all 30000 records.  Not necessary as far as I can tell.

Comment: The patch helped somewhat, but in the end not enough - we also had to split the list up into 26 hashed sub-lists :(